# Evaluation of 'not (False and True)'

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean

I came across this example ([*"Hacking Secret Ciphers with Python"*](https://inventwithpython.com/hackingciphers.pdf), p135) and I'm confused:

```
not (False and True)
```

The example states that it evaluates to `False`, but I fail to see why. If the parentheses modify the precedence then surely we are evaluating:

```
not (False)
```

Which evaluates to `True`, doesn't it? Or am I missing something?

```js
// output functions are configurable.  This one just appends some text
// to a pre element.
function outf(text) {
  var mypre = document.getElementById("output");
  mypre.innerHTML = mypre.innerHTML + text;
}

function builtinRead(x) {
  if (Sk.builtinFiles === undefined || Sk.builtinFiles["files"][x] === undefined)
    throw "File not found: '" + x + "'";
  return Sk.builtinFiles["files"][x];
}

// Here's everything you need to run a python program in skulpt
// grab the code from your textarea
// get a reference to your pre element for output
// configure the output function
// call Sk.importMainWithBody()
function runit() {
  var prog = document.getElementById("yourcode").value;
  var mypre = document.getElementById("output");
  mypre.innerHTML = '';
  Sk.pre = "output";
  Sk.configure({
    output: outf,
    read: builtinRead
  });
  (Sk.TurtleGraphics || (Sk.TurtleGraphics = {})).target = 'mycanvas';
  var myPromise = Sk.misceval.asyncToPromise(function() {
    return Sk.importMainWithBody("<stdin>", false, prog, true);
  });
  myPromise.then(function(mod) {
      console.log('success');
    },
    function(err) {
      console.log(err.toString());
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.skulpt.org/static/skulpt.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.skulpt.org/static/skulpt-stdlib.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<h3>Try This</h3> 
<form>
  <textarea id="yourcode" cols="40" rows="10">print(not (False and True))
  </textarea>
  <br />
  <button type="button" onclick="runit()">Run</button>
</form>
<pre id="output"></pre> 
<!-- If you want turtle graphics include a canvas -->
<div id="mycanvas"></div>
```

Comment: Have you *actually tried this*? `not (False and True)` evaluates to `True`.

Comment: I wasn't in a position to try it as all I had was the book and my phone! I think I can safely assume it's simply a typo in the book then!

Comment: Note that there are various online REPLs, so if you can post on SO you can run some code!

Comment: You are correct, never even thought to try it :)

Comment: The OP is right that this error occurs in the book cited.  Obviously the transcript isn't real.  My best guess is that the book meant to use `or`, not `and`: `not False or True` is True but `not (False or True)` is False.

Comment: Looking at the online version of the book, `not (False and False)` looks to be the correct version.

Comment: @user4957093: you could [run python online](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=b+%3D+not+(False+and+True)&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=1) (even on SO using http://skulpt.org).

Comment: Thanks for that, sculpt.org runs nicely on my phone :)

Comment: I've added a runnable Python snippet to the question as an example. Feel free to rollback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually covered in [the errata](http://inventwithpython.com/hacking/errata/):

> **Page 135**, the interactive shell should look like this:
>
> ```
> >>> not False and False # not False evaluates first 
> True 
> >>> not (False and False) # (False and False) evaluates first 
> False
> ```
>
> *(Thanks to Omer Chohan)*

It has been corrected in [the online version of the chapter](http://inventwithpython.com/hacking/chapter9.html), although not in the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

`not (False and True)` is definitely `True`, as you can see if you type the expression in the Python REPL.  Who's claiming it's `False`?

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't try typing it in as was no where near a computer, I'm reading 'Hacking Secret Ciphers with Python' from invent with python. Chapter 9.